# Why a function call is an xvalue (if return type is an rvalue)?

Tags: c++, c++11, xvalue, prvalue

Let's say we have a function:

```
struct A {
    int m;
};

A&& f();
```

As far as I know the expressions:

```
f();
f().m;
```

are both xvalue. But why? Why aren't they prvalue? I'm a little bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are returning by reference, not by value, from `f`. This implies that the `A` has a lifetime longer than `f()`, e.g.

```
A&& f()
{
     static A res;
     return std::move(res);
}
```

or

```
A global;

A&& f()
{
     return std::move(global);
}
```

But not

```
A&& f()
{
     return {}; // dangling reference
}
```

In `f().m;`, the use of `m` inherits the value category of the earlier sub-expression, as normal for member access.

Comment: Thank you! But what's the use of functions like these (moving from a local static and moving from a global)? Could you please explain do they have any practical usage? Can you provide an example that has practical usage?

Comment: @embedc You can have a header declaring `f` and the definition elsewhere, so `global` wouldn't be visible to the clients of `f`. It's not hugely compelling as a free function. A class's member function moving a data member is much more sensible.